# Issues regarding memory consumption and application crash

Tags: android, performance, out-of-memory, android-camera, android-memory

If I look at the memory consumption in devices such as Samsung S6 device through android studio,in first screen post the splash screen,it is consuming as 100 MB,If go to other activity which posses fragments it consumes nearly 70 MB,If i go to other activity,which launches camera application ,on taking the picture ,memory goes more than 224 MB,and crashes it is giving OOM Error while loading bitmap.
In Other scenarios such as If i do consecutive operations ,its crashes,
In Some Other cases,If i switching between tab also it crashes,

In HTC Devices such as 616,it is not crashing,it consumes for  overall usuage of 90 MB,for first screen around 40 MB,and its release automatically and also samung tab also not crashing.

My Question,is how can application consume 100 MB,in its first screen,Is it something related to Code which is going wrong?

Is it due to PNG file,reason for consumption?

Comment: What is the size and resolution of the image that you are using as a Splash screen?

Comment: Overall resource folder is less than 5 MB,Total size of splash screen and next screen is around 1.5 MB,each around 750 each,both are png,Is it due to that png,is it consuming more?.

Comment: Yes, maybe that can be the issue for you. sometimes the resolution of the image matters more than the size of the image, for memory usage.
A better example of this is given in this link: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#load-bitmap